# How to monitor GPU memory usage when training a DNN?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I give a result example. I want to ask how to get the data like this graph.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use pytorch commands such as [`torch.cuda.memory_stats`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.memory_stats) to get information about current GPU memory usage and then create a temporal graph based on these reports.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the [best](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.mem_get_info.html#:%7E:text=TORCH.CUDA.MEM_GET_INFO-,torch.cuda.mem_get_info,-%EF%BC%88%E8%AE%BE%E5%A4%87%3D%E6%97%A0%EF%BC%89)

`torch.cuda.mem_get_info`

it returns the global free and total GPU memory occupied for a given device using cudaMemGetInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is using `nvidia-smi` which looks like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   50C    P8    12W / 215W |   1088MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1091      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 24MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1158      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               48MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And use `subprocess` to get the string for example

```py
import subprocess
import re
command = 'nvidia-smi'
while True:
    p = subprocess.check_output(command)
    ram_using = re.findall(r'\b\d+MiB+ /', str(p))[0][:-5]
    ram_total = re.findall(r'/  \b\d+MiB', str(p))[0][3:-3]
    ram_percent = int(ram_using) / int(ram_total)
```

Or just split the line with `str(p).split('\n')` and count the string length